# Android Development: Theme typography doesn't work on button text

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

**I'm using jetpack compose, kotlin, on Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2. my app's targetSdk = 34**

The attached image pretty much sums up the problem.
After setting a custom theme with a custom typography, the theme's typography doesn't work on the text of a button.

**colors of the theme work on buttons normally**, only the typography isn't working.
**fonts work on buttons if i explicitly specify them**, but they're supposed to work automatically due to theme

i tried different fonts, same problem.
here's my implementation of the theme:

in `Theme.kt` file

```
@Composable
fun CutomTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    // irrelevant color-related code
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = CustomTypography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

in `CustomTypography` definition

```
val CustomTypography = Typography(
    bodyLarge = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = ReemKufi,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 24.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
    )
)
```

[image: attached image of problem]

Comment: Are you sure that your button uses body large typography as a standard value? Did you specify all typographies or just one?

Comment: @Krzysiulele oh this is it! it seems button use labelLarge typography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default TextStyle in Button (material 3) is not bodyLarge, [it is labelLarge](https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/applying-type#af6eb002-9cbb-4b64-bce6-1315d2252364).,

Another way you can see this is if you open the source code for Button you can see that the defined default text style is labelLarge:

> ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge)